# Highlight default button in ExtJS (3.x) MessageBox

Tags: button, extjs, messagebox

is there an Ext-sanctioned way to highlight the default button (the one triggered by pressing Enter) in Ext.MessageBox?

Please note that I do not want to do that by focusing the button when the MessageBox is shown (in case of a "prompt" dialog I want the input element to have focus).

I know I can do that by adding a custom class to the button element but ... maybe there is a better and more Ext-like way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short... no. Ext currently provides no method of highlighting a button in any of the `Ext.MessageBox` components, not via a config option anyway.

There are ways however, depending on the scenario. For example, if you're using `Ext.MessageBox.show()` (which you can actually use for all message boxes), then you can do something like...

```
new Ext.Msg.show({
   title: 'Test',
   msg: 'A sample message box with a button marked as default',
   buttons: { ok: '<b>Submit</b>', cancel: 'Cancel' },
   fn: function(btn) {
       if(btn == 'ok') {
          //do something
       }
   },
   icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING
}
```

All we've done is add `<b>` tags to one of the buttons in our config, this would show it in bold obviously.

The other way that you've mentioned is to add a custom class and mark the button in a colour of text, you could even just add the class like we did with the `<b>` tags above to make it easier..

`buttons: { ok: '<span class="highlighted-option">Submit</span>', cancel: 'Cancel' },`

Other than this style of approach, or without extending the `Ext.MessageBox` class, there's no other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 7):

In ExtJs 4 you can set the default button as follows:

```
Ext.MessageBox.defaultButton = buttonIndex;
```

Where 'buttonIndex' is the index of the button on the dialog. You need to do this before you call Ext.MessageBox.Show.

Comment: I can't remember off hand whether the buttons start at base index 0 or 1, but it's simply based on the number of buttons (counting from the left) in the footer bar. For example (assuming zero based index), if you have 'yes', 'no' as buttons in the footer bar, 'yes' would be the first button (index 0) and 'no' the second button (index 1). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Jaitsu has the best answer, but in case this might be useful to somebody else... here is a way to do that with styles.
The same trick can be applied to any other button (like: Window buttons).

Add this to your css:

```
.x-btn-default td.x-btn-mc {
  outline: 1px dotted black;
}
```

Then define buttons like this:

```
  ...
  ,buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Ok',
      ,handler: handleFn
      ,cls: 'x-btn-default'
    },{
      text: 'Cancel',
      ,handler: handleFn
    }
  ]
  ,...
```